# retrieve data in angular with specific list

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular8

I need to get family list of user 
 my Api get this 
this is the data we get

```
{
    "id": 16,
    "username": "omar",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 39,
    "knownAs": "Omar Talaat",
    "created": "2017-07-11T00:00:00",
    "lastActive": "2020-02-19T16:51:50.0251608",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "mobileNumber": "0114006884",
    "city": "October city ",
    "country": "Egypt",
    "photoUrl": "http://res.cloudinary.com/drm7h8ge0/image/upload/v1577009358/wk0k06fkbbkt0vbnjvic.jpg",
    "photos": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "url": ,
            "description": null,
            "dateAdded": "2019-12-22T12:09:16.9949907",
            "isMain": true
        },
        {
            "id": 1007,
            "url":,
            "description": null,
            "dateAdded": "2019-12-26T01:26:48.8852864",
            "isMain": false
        }
    ],
    "families": [
        {
            "id": 1028,
            "familyName": "Othman",
            "father": {
                "id": 1028,
                "firstName": "Omar Talaat",
                "lastName": "Othman",
                "job": " pharmasict",
                "mobileNumber": 1254879,
                "emailAdress": "domar@yahoo.com",
                "isExest": true
            },
            "mother": {
                "id": 1028,
                "firstName": "marium",
                "lastName": "Abd Rabo ",
                "job": "Doctor",
                "mobileNumber": 1254879,
                "emailAdress": "maruim@htomail",
                "isExest": true
            },
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressName": "1 kdsk  kjhduu",
                    "city": " october city",
                    "country": "Egypt"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1029,
            "familyName": "update-talaat",
            "father": {
                "id": 1029,
                "firstName": "omar",
                "lastName": "talaat",
                "job": "update-farmacist",
                "mobileNumber": 21547,
                "emailAdress": "omar@gmail.com",
                "isExest": false
            },
            "mother": {
                "id": 1029,
                "firstName": "marium",
                "lastName": "gonzales",
                "job": "update-doctor",
                "mobileNumber": 13654,
                "emailAdress": "mariumgonzales@hotmail.com",
                "isExest": true
            },
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressName": "1,update- mohamed streest ",
                    "city": "giza",
                    "country": "egypt"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

interface for user:-

```
import { Photo } from './photo';
import { Family } from './family';

export interface User {
    id: number;
    num: number;
    username: string;
    knownAs: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    created: Date;
    lastActive: Date;
    photoUrl: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    emailAdress: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    mobileNumber: string;
    photos?: Photo[];
    family?: Family[];
}
```

family interface:-

```
import { Address } from './address';
import { Father } from './father';
import { Mother } from './mother';



export interface Family {

    id: number;
    familyName: string;
    father: Father;
    mother: Mother;
    addresses: Address[];

}
```

and my user service like that:

```
baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  users: User[];

constructor( private http: HttpClient , private authService: AuthService) { }


  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
 return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users' );
}


 getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id);

  }

getFamilies(): Observable<Family[]> {
  return this.http.get<Family[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + this.authService.decodedToken.nameid + '/families' );
}
 getFamily( id): Observable<Family> {
  return this.http.get<Family>(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + this.authService.decodedToken.nameid + '/families/' + id);
 }
```

this is MemberDetailsResolver :-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve,  ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserService } from '../_service/user.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_service/alertify.service';
import { AuthService } from '../_service/auth.service';

@Injectable(

)

export class MemberDetailsResolver implements Resolve<User> {

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router,
                private alertify: AlertifyService , private authService: AuthService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User> {
        return this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.alertify.error('Proplem retriving data');
                this.router.navigate(['/CampList']);
                return of(null);
            })
        );
    }

}
```

this my member family card component:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Family } from 'src/app/_models/family';
import { User } from 'src/app/_models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-family-card',
  templateUrl: './member-family-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-family-card.component.css']
})
export class MemberFamilyCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() family: Family[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

member family card html:-

```
<div *ngFor="let family of family">
<div class="card mb-4"style="max-width: 202px;" >
  <!-- Image -->
 <div class="car-img-wrapper">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{'../../../assets/img/person-placeholder.jpg'}}">
         <ul class="list-inline member-icons animate text-center">

             <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/family/',family.id]"  ><i class="fa fa-user"></i></button></li>

             <!-- 
             <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="btn btn-primary"
                [routerLink]="['/members/',family.id]" [queryParams]="{tab : 3}" ><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button></li>
            -->
         </ul>
 </div>
     <div class="card-body p-1">
       <h5 class="card-title text-center mb-1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><strong>Family Name: </strong>{{family.familyName}}</h5>

     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

this member details:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/_models/user';
import { FakeMissingTranslationHandler } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Family } from 'src/app/_models/family';
import { TabsetComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/_service/user.service';
import { AlertifyService } from 'src/app/_service/alertify.service';
import { NgxGalleryOptions, NgxGalleryImage, NgxGalleryAnimation } from 'ngx-gallery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-details',
  templateUrl: './member-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-details.component.css']
})
export class MemberDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('memberTabs', {static: true}) memberTabs: TabsetComponent;
  user: User;
  galleryOptions: NgxGalleryOptions[];
  galleryImages: NgxGalleryImage[];


  constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data.user;
  });

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const selectTab = params.tab;
      this.memberTabs.tabs[selectTab > 0 ? selectTab : 0].active = true;
    });

    this.galleryOptions = [
      {
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px',
        imagePercent: 100,
        thumbnailsColumns: 4,
        imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide,
        preview: false
      }
    ];
    this.galleryImages = this.user.photos.map(photo => ({
      small: photo.url,
      medium: photo.url,
      big: photo.url,
      description: photo.description
    })
    );
  }



 selectTab(tabId: number) {
  this.memberTabs.tabs[tabId].active = true;
}
}
```

this is member details html

```
<div  class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <div >
    <h1>   your Profile </h1>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       <app-member-card [user]="user"></app-member-card>

    </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="tab-panel">
        <tabset class="member-tabset" #memberTabs>
          <tab heading="My Detailes">


          </tab>
          <tab heading="  My Photos" >

            <ngx-gallery [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryImages"></ngx-gallery>

          </tab>

          <tab heading="family">
            <h4>Family detailes</h4>


            <app-member-family-card [family]="user.family"></app-member-family-card>




          </tab>

          <tab heading="My Child">
            <h4>my Child</h4>

          </tab>    
        </tabset>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the family for user

Comment: And what is your problem? I want to do something is not a good problem description

Comment: it not give me the family list of the user